# Football coaches who have won multiple FIFA World Cups

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup, coaching

Has there been any coach(manager) that has won the world cup more than once? If so, please provide the manager's name, winning years and team(s) managed.

Comment: See also Wikipedia: [FIFA World Cup records - Coaches: tournament position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup_records#Coaches:_tournament_position). About players: [List of players who have won multiple FIFA World Cups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_players_who_have_won_multiple_FIFA_World_Cups)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Italy's Vittorio Pozzo was the first person to have won two FIFA World Cups as a coach (1934, 1938)

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vittorio_Pozzo)

Answer (score 2):

Jill Ellis has won consecutive FIFA World Cups in 2015 and 2019 as a coach, the second person to do so.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jill_Ellis)

Comment: Unless you wrote something wrong, that's not what "consecutive" means.